# NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/BinaryJedisCluster

Tags: java, jedis

`Message=org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/BinaryJedisCluster$60,Cause=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/BinaryJedisCluster$60,className=redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster,methodName=srem,lineNum=700`

`org.springframework.boot 2.3.4.RELEASE <jedis.version>3.3.0</jedis.version> <redis.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</redis.version>`

this error only exists in our product environment after processed request, The problem doesnot occurs in local develop environment.

i want to know how to deal the problem